# TypeError: load_dotenv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'encoding'

Tags: python, ubuntu, flask, dotenv

After installing ubuntu OS I got this error while before everything was working fine.

I don't know which version of dotenv I was using before.
but now I installed with this command.
pip3 install python-dotenv

Comment: Try running `load_dotenv` without passing in `encoding`?

Comment: I'm not giving any parameter to load_dotenv()

Comment: Can you please send the offending code?

Answer (score 0):

This option from (https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/) worked for me

Here's what I had in the root directory

Root dir had:
.env
app.py
templates
requirements.txt

In my .env file, I had already listed the environment variables as below:
FLASK_APP=app.py
FLASK_ENV=development

However, after typing "flask run" to run the application I go the error same as you did:

TypeError: load_dotenv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'encoding'

---

How to fix it

1. Download a virtual environment to ubuntu (I use Ubuntu 20.04).
   $ sudo apt install python3.8-env
   $ python3.8 -m venv venv
2. If you type ls you'll notive a new folder with the name venv.
    Activate the virtual env
   $ source ./venv/bin/acivate
3. Install modules in requirements.txt (assuming you have dotenv included, else install using: $ pip3 install python-dotenv)
   $ pip3 install -r requirements.txt
4. You can add the dotenv cli using
   $ pip3 install "python-dotenv[cli]"
5. Run your application using (don't ignore the space between -- and python in the below command):
   $ dotenv run -- python app.py